# How to join a function with a table and pass table columns as parameter to that function in snowflake

Tags: function, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How to join a function with a table and pass table columns as parameter to that function.

While using the common syntax like :

```sql
select * 
    from favorite_years y join table(favorite_colors(y.year)) c;
```

I am getting error :

> SQL Error [2031] [42601]: SQL compilation error:
> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Comment: we need more information to debug - does it work with a simple function? can you share the function?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this example of a table function to run properly:

```
create or replace function favorite_colors ( year number )
  returns table (color string)
as 
 'select color from colors where yearid = YEAR';

create or replace table favorite_years (year integer);
insert into favorite_years values (2020),(2021),(2022);
create or replace table colors (yearid integer, color string);
insert into colors values (2021,'red'),(2022,'orange'),(2020, 'blue');


select * from favorite_years y join table(favorite_colors(y.year)) c;
```